# Saw a show about 5 or 6 years ago where a kid gets these crystals and then he can turn into the animal that gave him the crystal

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I think it began with a Z, and I think title was something like *Zanimal* but I can't find it. His first crystal, he turns into an orange and white tiger. Also later in the show he meets a giant tree and I don't have any idea what it was it was style  a 3d cgi I know it's not huntik and magi but other than that I'm not sure

Comment: How long ago was "years ago"? What sort of animation was it? Sketchy? Realistic? Stylized? Pen-and-ink drawings? 3D CGI? Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if you can [edit] some more details in.

Comment: Was about 8 or 9 years ago and was 3 d cgi from what I remember